# Test if a url exist in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I am a newbie in android and speak a 'poor' english .

I have a fragment where i have to test  **if a url exist**   before to execute a webview.

In my first test i got a "*android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException*"

So , i use a **AsyncTask**

How can test in my fragment activity if the url exist ??

I test under Android Studio and in debug  'doInBackground' is not executed ???

In advance ,Many thanks for your support

---

**here is my class AsyncTask:**

```
public class ExistUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

   private static final String TAG = "CheckURL";
   String filename="";

   public ExistUrl(String URL) {
    this.filename=URL;
    Log.d(TAG, "url="+ this.filename);
  }

 @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
      //  validateParams(params);
        Log.v("name of file",this.filename);
        Boolean OK =MyUtilities.exists(params[0]);
        Log.v("***********  retour     exists class:", Boolean.toString(OK));

    return OK;
    }

   @Override
   protected void onCancelled() {
    super.onCancelled();
    Log.i(TAG, "Background cancelled.");
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
    super.onPostExecute(result);
       String message = null;
       if (result)
           message = "Url  succeeded.";
       else
           message = "Url failed.";
       Log.i(TAG, message);                               }
   }}
```

**Here is Myutilities.exists**

```
    public static boolean exists(String URLName){

    try {
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
        // note : you may also need
        //        HttpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)
        HttpURLConnection con =
                (HttpURLConnection) new URL(URLName).openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        return (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
  }
```

**My fragment activity**

```
    public class HainautFragment extends Fragment {

    public HainautFragment(){}

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                           View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hainaut, container, false);
    String Zone = "http://www.tournoi.org/tournoilive/affiche_categorie_dbf.asp?nuclb=1005&datedeb=2013/9/13&datefin=2013/9/22&IdTournoi=309569";

                        ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(getActivity());
                        Boolean isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
                        if (isInternetPresent) {

                                new ExistUrl(Zone).execute();

        *********************//how to test return***************************

                                                       }
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pass url here

```
new ExistUrl(Zone).execute(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
if (isInternetPresent) {

     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
          new ExistUrl(Zone).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, new String[]{null});
     else
          new ExistUrl(Zone).execute(new String[]{null});

}
```

then once you assign url to filename string like this `this.filename=URL;` no need to use again `this.filename` just use `filename`

```
public ExistUrl(String URL) {
    this.filename=URL;
    Log.d(TAG, "url="+ filename);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Your sending `Boolean OK =MyUtilities.exists(params[0]);` send like this
 `MyUtilities.exists(filename);`

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
    Log.v("name of file",filename);                    //Correction here
    Boolean OK =MyUtilities.exists(filename);          //Correction here
    Log.v("***********  retour     exists class:", Boolean.toString(OK));

return OK;
}
```